# Как получить данные из json в python?

Tags: python, json

Имеется json файл такого содержания:

```
[
  {
    "105": {
      "city": "Moscow",
      "time": "15:20"
    }
  },
  {
    "107": {
      "city": "Tokio",
      "time": "16:50"
    }
  },
  {
    "108": {
      "city": "London",
      "time": "11:20"
    }
  }
]
```

Как можно получить и записать в переменную значение "city", например, из словаря "108"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если смотреть, что 105, 107, 108 находятся в разных массивах, тогда код будет вот таким:

```
import json

var = '[ { "105": { "city": "Moscow", "time": "15:20" } }, { "107": { "city": "Tokio", "time": "16:50" } }, { "108": { "city": "London", "time": "11:20" } } ]'
data = json.loads(var)
print(data[0]["105"]["city"]) # Moscow
print(data[1]["107"]["city"]) # Tokio
print(data[2]["108"]["city"]) # London
```

Если всё это будет в одном:

```
[
  {
    "105": {
      "city": "Moscow",
      "time": "15:20"
    },
    "107": {
      "city": "Tokio",
      "time": "16:50"
    },
    "108": {
      "city": "London",
      "time": "11:20"
    }
  }
]
```

Тогда код будет вот таким:

```
data = json.loads(var)
print(data[0]["105"]["city"]) # Moscow
print(data[0]["107"]["city"]) # Tokio
print(data[0]["108"]["city"]) # London
```